# Appending links to new rows in pandas df after using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, append

I'm attempting to extract some links from a chunk of beautiful soup html and append them to rows of a new pandas dataframe.

So far, I have this code:

```
url = "http://www.reed.co.uk/jobs
datecreatedoffset=Today&isnewjobssearch=True&pagesize=100"
r = ur.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BShtml(r, "html.parser")
adcount = soup.find_all("div", class_="pages")
print(adcount)
```

From my output I then want to take every link, identified by href="" and store each one in a new row of a pandas dataframe.

Using the above snippet I would end up with 6 rows in my new dataset.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The url you provided gives a 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your links gives a 404 but the logic should be the same as below. You just need to extract the anchor tags with the *page* class and join them to the base url:

```
import  pandas as pd
from urlparse import urljoin
import requests 

base = "http://www.reed.co.uk/jobs"

url = "http://www.reed.co.uk/jobs?keywords=&location=&jobtitleonly=false"
r = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["links"], data=[urljoin(base, a["href"]) for a in  soup.select("div.pages a.page")])

print(df)
```

Which gives you:

```
                                            links
0    http://www.reed.co.uk/jobs?cached=True&pageno=2
1    http://www.reed.co.uk/jobs?cached=True&pageno=3
2    http://www.reed.co.uk/jobs?cached=True&pageno=4
3    http://www.reed.co.uk/jobs?cached=True&pageno=5
4  http://www.reed.co.uk/jobs?cached=True&pageno=...
5    http://www.reed.co.uk/jobs?cached=True&pageno=2
```

Comment: Thank you Padraic. And apologies for the slow reply - this is a side project and i haven't had the chance to look at it again until now. This is exactly what I was looking for though and would've taken me much longer to figure out. 

I changed the URL slightly so i'm just getting today's posts, and that the page limit is 100. In the end it looked like this:

Comment: `code` import  pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import requests 

base = "http://www.reed.co.uk/jobs"

url = "http://www.reed.co.uk/jobs?datecreatedoffset=Today&pagesize=100"
r = requests.get(url).content
soup = BShtml(r, "html.parser")

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["links"], data=[urljoin(base, a["href"]) for a in  soup.select("div.pages a.page")])
df`code`

Comment: Sorry about that previous post. It should be:

`import  pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import requests 

base = "http://www.reed.co.uk/jobs"

url = "http://www.reed.co.uk/jobs?datecreatedoffset=Today&pagesize=100"
r = requests.get(url).content
soup = BShtml(r, "html.parser")

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["links"], data=[urljoin(base, a["href"]) for a in  soup.select("div.pages a.page")])
df`